# Device: Check current user before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How to check current user before login.
Simply I want to call my method before login.
Suppose I have two different - 2 login form and I am already login from first login form and when I will log in from another login form then it will check user already logged in  or not.
I want to create a custom method which will call before login.

Comment: Are you using devise for authentication?

Comment: Yes but right now i want to check current user before login.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your question.
You want to a before_action method where you can check whether user already has session or not.

You can do it by writing your method in

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :check_user_exists

  def check_user_exists
     #Your logic to check authorization token
  end
end
```

.
This will be called before any action as all controllers are inherited by ApplicationController.

Comment: Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Hello @desha it will call before every action. I want when user login with the device only.

Comment: @RahulSharma You can put a condition with before_action like : 
`before_action :check_user_exists if device_exists?`